# CVS - partial merge

Tags: eclipse, cvs, merge

I have some files in branch b1 that have gone trough several revisions. E.g., r1, r2 and r3.
I want to merge those files into HEAD but only changes made in revisions r1 and r3, not the ones in r2.
With eclipse I can merge only the changes that I want manually and then I can save the file and commit the changes to HEAD.
How can I later merge the remaining differences made in r2?
If I make a merge again, the diferences made in r2 won't show up.

Is what I want to do possible at all?
 - With eclipse?
 - With CVS command line?
 - Not with CVS but with another Version Control System (VCS)?
 - Which one?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge the changes from r1 and r3, save the file but do NOT mark the file as merged.
Commit the changes made to the file.
That way the next time you are going to perform a merge, the differences made in r2 will show.

Answer (score 0):

With CVS you pretty much have to do it manually for every merge. Some other version control systems allow to manipulate with individual changes, e.g. git or mercurial.